# Dummy variables vs deleting observations

Tags: regression, measurement-error

I am trying to figure out whether a general (simple rule) exists for my problem.
Specifically, if I have a dataset where some variables (independent/control; not the dependent one) may be measured with errors and I know for which specific observations this happens is it better to control with dummy variables or to remove those observations from the sample (supposing that the removal does not cause issues related to non-random sampling)?

My idea was as follows:

- remove them in case of a few observations affected by the issue
- control with a dummy in case of many observations affected

Regressions on these data are generally cross-sectional

Edit: Starting variables are integers and >0. They are the number of customers and suppliers and other measures built starting from them (e.g., number/proportion of foreign customers. In this case they are generally real numbers >0)

Comment: Are the variables measured with error continuous?

Comment: @num_39 Starting variables are integers and >0. They are the number of customers and suppliers and other measures built starting from them (e.g., number/proportion of foreign customers. In this case they are generally real numbers >0)

Comment: Thanks. And are they simply measured with error such that variance is increased or are they also biased?

Comment: @num_39 in specific industries (e.g., electronics) the starting numbers (number of customers/suppliers) may be higher than the real ones; I suppose thus they are biased

Comment: Have you considered sample weighting to assign less weight to observations with measurement errors? Do you know the variance of this measurement error?

Answer (score 2):

If you are working on an `inference` problem, inspecting the relationship between `X` and `y`, and trying to talk about the size of an effect and its statistical significance, then your most straightforward solution is to drop the data points with measurement error.

As a check, you can re-run the model with the problematic observations *included* and show the solution remains robust, perhaps still significant, but the size of the effect changes based on the direction of the measurement error. If this check works, you can argue, based on the result and possibly other domain knowledge, that non-random sampling was *not* introduced by dropping those data points.

If you are working on `prediction`, discarding data seems like a waste, especially if you know something about the measurement error. In such a case, it might be worthwhile to compare metrics (e.g. `F1-score`) for several models: 1. without problematic points; 2. with problematic points and a dummy variable indicating measurement error; 3. model with imputed "corrected" values for problematic data points.

By using cross-validation, you should be able to decide which model works best out of the sample.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do regression on such data, records with missing values would be deleted.
Now, a dummy (one-hot) variable would tell you one thing. Still, the real action is imputing the missing values with special values, which for numerical variables would be either 0, mean, below the lowest or other, so it doesn't change your distribution much. If you want to bin your numerical inputs, you can categorize and leave the missing values in a separate category—do one-hot for all categories.
In the case of other algorithms, trees work well with dummies due to the splitting logic. However, they won't predict any unseen values if you use tree regressors.